# Android 3.0: Is there a built-in navigation pane? (screenshot)

Tags: android

On Android 3.0, is there a built-in widget to create a navigation pane like the one on the left side?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hardly.. that navigation area is built w/ fragments.  The bar at the top is an actionbar.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: I'm aware that it's using fragments, I was just wondering if there was a built-in widget that would let me throw my own fragments into the right pane while still providing that fancy navigation pane.